# Using (not abusing) ContinueWith

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Suppose we have 2 worker functions:

```
void Step1(); // Maybe long.
void Step2(); // Might be short clean up of step 1.
```

I often see:

```
Task.Run(() => Step1()).ContinueWith(t => Step2());
```

Which creates **2 tasks** which run in **series**.
When:

```
Task.Run(() => { Step1(); Step2(); });
```

Which creates a **single task** which runs the 2 functions in **series**, might appear to be a SIMPLER choice.

Are there common sense guidelines that can be applied to determine when a continuation is actaully required over the simpler approach?
The above examples don't have exception handling - to what extend does exception handling affect those guidelines?

Comment: If you have two synchronous methods to call in series then it makes sense to create just **one** task for this job. `Task.ContinueWith` is a special mechanism to combine **asynchronous** methods into synchronous job.

Answer (score 7):

> Are there common sense guidelines that can be applied to determine
>   when a continuation is actaully required over the simpler approach?

`ContinueWith` provides you with the ability to invoke `Step2` only on certain conditions via the [`TaskContinutationOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx), such as `OnlyOnCanceled` `OnlyOnFaulted`, `OnlyOnRanToCompletion`, and more. That way, you can compose a workflow which is suitable for each case.

You could also do this with a single `Task.Run` and a `try-catch`, but that would probably be more for you to maintain.

Personally, I attempt to avoid using `ContinueWith` as I find `async-await` to be less verbose, and more synchronous like. I would rather `await` inside a `try-catch`.

Comment: It's especially hard to maintain the `try-catch`es when you have more than two steps, some of which should run when faulted, and some of which shouldn't. It happens. Of course, you could use something like an error monad instead of a `Task`. `await` is a good alternative for continuations on async I/O, but you still need `ContinueWith` sometimes - e.g. when awaiting a tree of operations, rather than a "stack".

Comment: @Luaan It's hard and unreadable. Would be a pain to maintain multiple continuations like that.

Comment: You don't have to do it entirely manually - a great benefit of `Task`s (and e.g. the error monad) is that they are easily composed. The whole of error handling can be handled in a helper method, for example (`HandleErrors(anotherTask)`), which makes it amazingly easy to both read and write. Try doing the same with `try-catch` :D

Answer (score 3):

There's two main reasons I see:

1. Composition

The `ContinueWith` approach allows you to easily compose many different tasks, and use helper methods to build "continuation trees". Changing this to imperative calls limits this - it's still possible, but tasks are much more composable than imperative code.

2. Error handling

In the `ContinueWith` case, `Step2` always runs, even if `Step1` throws. This could be emulated with a `try` clause, of course, but it's a bit trickier. Most importantly, it doesn't compose, and it doesn't scale well - if you find you have to run multiple steps, each with their own error handling, you're going to struggle *a lot* with `try-catch`es. Of course, `Task`s aren't the only solution to this, nor are they necessarily the best - an error monad will allow you to compose interdependent operations easily as well.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, use the least amount of continuations that will do. They clutter the code and cost performance.

One reason to do this is exception behavior. The continuation will run even if the first task failed. Here, there is no error behavior as far as I can tell. This does not seem to be an issue in this particular piece of code. You would somehow need to process the exception from `t`.

Often, people are thinking "I have a pipeline!" and are decomposing the pipeline into steps. That's natural to think. But the pipeline steps do not necessarily need to manifest in the form of continuations. They can just be sequenced method calls.

Comment: Performance probably isn't an issue - any place where you'd use CPU-tasks anyway would also be a place where the overhead from additional continuations is negligible. Unless you're on a GUI-scheduler, of course...

Answer (score 1):

`ContinueWith` will run, even when the first task yielded an exception (check `t.Exception`).

A `ContinueWith` can be seen as an asynchronous `finally` in a `try..catch` statement. And that is exactly what makes it useful. Also you can fine-grain when the `ContinueWith` is called.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there common sense guidelines that can be applied to determine
>   when a continuation is actaully required over the simpler approach?

Most likely you'll use `ContinueWith` When you :

- Need to work with *TPL*(for example you work with method from 3rd party library that returns Task)
- May require to use chains of callbacks
- May require to run some callback method only for those tasks that finished execution with certain result (faulty tasks for example)

And it's likely that you'll use simpler approach when :

- You use methods that doesn't return Task
- You just want to invoke two or more methods synchronously on one thread

Answer (score 0):

First of all I assume you need to do asynchronous job:

```
public async void Step1(){ /* bla*/ }

public async void Step2(){ /* bla*/ }
```

Then call should be:

```
public async void taskRunner(){
    await Task.Run(() => { await Step1(); await Step2(); }); 
}
```

In second place to be sure it will work like `Continue with` you have to add exception handling (second task is always executed even if first ends with exception.

```
public async void taskRunner(){
    await Task.Run(() => { 
        try{
            await Step1(); 
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        await Step2(); 
    }); 
}
```

Another point is that tasks can be lambdas, and as such they can just take previous task result and unpack it into the next task, that requires an extra variable if done without `ContinueWith`:

```
 double[] nums = { 3,5,2,6,5,4,3 };
 await Task.Run(() => { //still missing exception handling here ;)
        double result = await GetSum( nums); 
        await SubtractValue(nums, result); 
    });
```

With `ContinueWith`

```
 double[] nums = { 3,5,2,6,5,4,3 };
 await Task.Run( () => await GetSum(nums))
     .ContinueWith( t => await SubtractValue(nums, t.Result));
```

In this particular case there's no syntax gain, but there could be even more complex examples that is just unfeasible write without the help of ContinueWith:

Also worth to note that the compiler is smart enough to optimize the code in 2 different cases to be the same so you have to choose (unless you require a particular behaviour) wich way is the more clear to you.

I hope I made no error, I not checked if the code compile, sorry for that but is late here, I will correct the answer tomorrow in case.